# Datetime conversion in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript

How to convert 10/jan/2010 to 10/01/2010 using JavaScript or jQuery

Kindly help me

Answer (score 2):

There's no month string representation like that in javascript, so you have to define that yourself for starters:

```
var months = {jan: '01', feb: '02', mar: '03', apr: '04', may: '05', jun: '06',
              jul: '07', aug: '08', sep: '09', oct: '10', nov: '11', dec: '12'};
```

Now, given a date

```
var datestring = '10/jan/2010';
```

You need to first filter out your month segment:

```
var monthpart = datestring.split('/')[1];
```

And then do a simple replace:

```
var datestring = datestring.replace(monthpart, months[monthpart]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) we use it in our web app.
A warning though... the localisation architecture of the lib makes it a pain to load dynamically.

And be sure to fetch the svn version, there are(was?) some bugs in the downloadable version.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here.
http://github.com/vitch/jquery-methods/raw/master/date.js
Its cool and it does pretty good job for all the possibilities and error handling is also pretty good.

```
var d1 = Date.parse('10/jan/2010');
alert(d1.toString('dd/mm/yyyy'));
```